# Change font color of text in a perticular row of a particular table

Tags: angular

I want to change the font color of a particular row in a  table by using `ngClass` but it is not working.

I am doing this

```
[ngClass]="{'total':item.key === 'Total'}"
```

and in the css I have:

```
.total {
    background: white !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: green !important;
}
```

Background color is working, and `font-weight: bold` also working that means this class is applied  but still color is not changing.

When I inspect I see this

```
td[_ngcontent-c1] {
    color: #808080; 
}
```

How can I override this if `!important` is also not working?

I am using `td color: #808080;` in so many places so I cannot change this.

Comment: did you try to add that style after `td[_ngcontent-c1] {` ?

Comment: @MihaiIorga, I just tried this. no luck.

Comment: @HrishikeshKale, what difference will it create when the class is already applied with '==='?

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply color as below

option 1

```
<td [style.color]='condition?"#color1":"#color2">
```

option 2

```
<td [style.color]="{'total':item.key === 'Total'}">
```

First option is generic and second one as per your condition.

Another issue with your code. `color: green !important;` given as **important**. Either remove important or add important to td class

```
td[_ngcontent-c1] {
    color: #808080 !important; 
}
```

Comment: but there are so many td that means i need to apply on every td. actually I just want in only at the last row of a table.

Comment: in-line css have priority over css, so I'll choose use [style.color] or [ngStyle]. If is a last row of a table that you use a *ngFor, use *ngFor="..;let last=last" and use [ngStyle]={'color':last?green:black}

Comment: @Eliseo Inline css will ignore if you gave an !important.

Comment: @ShabbirDhangot ::glups::, sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
[class.total]="item.key === 'Total'"
```

But it seems your class is not applied because the expression is evaluated to false.

Make sure item.key is equal to 'Total'.

For testing purpose you can try:

```
<td [class.total]="item.key === 'Total'"> {{item.key}} - {{item.key === 'Total'}} </td>
```

This way you will see if your condition is evaluated as being true.

Comment: class is already applied because background: white !important; is working. it is just the font-color which is not changing.

Comment: If your class worked, you should see this when inspecting: <td _ngcontent-c0 class="total">